# SSO authentication token revocation issue with pac4j (multiple providers)

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, single-sign-on, saml

In a webapp using the pac4j dependency to implement SSO support, I encounter an issue.

Context:

- Java EE/JRE 1.7.0.79, Tomcat 7.0.70, org.springframework:spring:3.2.16.RELEASE, org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.9.RELEASE, org.pac4j:spring-security-pac4j:1.4.1, org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:1.8.3, org.pac4j:pac4j-saml:1.8.3
- Multiple 3rd-party authentication providers are enabled in the webapp configuration (say Google OAuth and any SAML), forwarded to UI as 2 buttons on the login page: "Login with Google", "Login with my_SAML_provider_label"

Requirements:

- Upgrading Java or/and Tomcat is an option. Upgrading spring and pac4j is not
- Do not use Spring annotations injection, anytime possible

Issue enduser-sequence:

- 1/ Click "Login with Google" (useragent is redirected to Google's authentication page)
- 2/ Authenticate properly on the Google page, with an outer-user that will or will not match any of your local app users upon callback
- 3/ Go back to the local webapp login page
- 4/ Click "Login with my_SAML_provider_label" now (useragent is redirected to the provider authentication page)
- 5/ Authenticate properly on the 3rd-party page, with an outer-user that will or will not match any of your local app users upon callback
- 6/ Assert the following exception in logs: org.pac4j.oauth.profile.google2.Google2Profile cannot be cast to org.pac4j.saml.profile.SAML2Profile

Issue stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.pac4j.oauth.profile.google2.Google2Profile cannot be cast to org.pac4j.saml.profile.SAML2Profile
at com.company.module.sso.SAMLAuthenticationService.retrieveAuthenticatedUser(SAMLAuthenticationService.java:59)
..
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.company.module.filters.ApplicationAvailabilityFilter.doFilter(ApplicationAvailabilityFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.company.module.filters.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.company.module.filters.ChronoFilter.doFilter(ChronoFilter.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.company.module.filters.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Related sourcecode:

applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
    ..
    <beans:bean id="clientFilter" class="org.pac4j.springframework.security.web.ClientAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/outer-authentication"/>
        <beans:property name="clients" ref="clients" />
        <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>
    ..
    <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />
</beans:beans>
```

SAMLAuthenticationService.java:

```
..
ClientAuthenticationToken token = null;
try {
    token = (ClientAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    final SAML2Profile samlProfile = (SAML2Profile) token.getUserProfile(); // L59
    ..
} finally {
    token.eraseCredentials(); // troubleshooting: not clearing credentials made no difference
}
..
```

Observations:

- The same issue can be obtained by first attempting a login through the SAML provider, then through the Google one: the user-sequence order seems irrelevant
- A workaround is to stop Tomcat, clean its work directory, then restart it
- Either way is to wait for the initial authentication token (callbacked/obtained from provider 1) to expire (expiration delay set to 1h through the pac4j configuration I/O)
- Issue will bump again, as soon as the faulty sequence is performed again by the enduser

Guess:

- Related to an improper revocation of the authentication token of the previous SSO authentication (callbacked/obtained from provider 1), before attempting to read the authentication token of the current authentication process (callbacked/obtained from provider 2)
- Indirectly, due to an improper use of org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy (my implementation in the Spring Security XML configuration seems standard/defaults)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it seems: Spring security's `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();` must have been being invoked, before any situation where a jump from one provider to another one may occur.

Such situations may be:

- the remote-user was successfuly authenticated by the SSO provider but matches no local-user
- the local-user is already signed on the local-app through an SSO provider, but browsed or got redirected to the local-app homepage, and may then attempt an SSO authentication through another SSO provider
- the local-user asked or got redirected to the logout URL: while destroying the web session, this should also clear the Spring security's context

I did not test concurrency scenarios yet (1 local-user authenticating through different browsers through different SSO providers, multiple users), so even if I can assert the initial issue is solved, that may still have side-effects (dropping the intended-user context (desired), but also other users contexts (undesired)).

User authentication exists within 1 session, while the security context exists within 1 thread. So I'm a bit lost in order to get the proper grip on it.